# Skype and WAMP conflicting

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, window

Skype and Wamp Conflict. I have to quit skype and then switch on WAMP server otherwise, my WAMP server never starts.

Is there a way to which we can align them at boot up time that WAMP should start first then skype. (Both use port 80)

What is the **solution**?

Comment: Not poart of an answer, but pretty please do not connect any XP machine to any Internet facing network unless you are on the extended support contract (which IIRC is Eur 40k per machine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can set Skype to not use Port 80.

1. In Skype, click on Tools –> Options
2. Click on “Advanced”
3. Click on “Connection”
4. Remove the tick at “Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections”
5. Click Save
6. Exit and then restart Skype

Let me know if it works!

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: Yes Boss it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Same question on StackOverflow was closed, due to being offtopic, so I couldn't write my answer there. So instead I am answering here.

As of Skype 8, the method described by skjerns is **no longer an option**. You can't assign another port to Skype - at least not from Skype itself.

The solution is to go to the **Windows Firewall** and block the access of Skype to port 80. To do so, follow the steps below:

1. Open up the Start menu and search for Firewall. Open up the result that states "Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security" or "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security".
2. On the left side, go to Inbound Rules and search for "Skype". There will be 2 entries, you will have to do the next steps to both of them.
3. Right click on "Skype", click on "Properties".
4. Under the "Protocols and Ports" tab, set the "Local-" and the "Remote port" to "Specific Ports" and enter a port below, that you do not think is being used by another program. I've chosen to enter port 5000. If that won't work for you, try assigning another port. There are plenty of websites online that help you determine what applications are using a specific port, you can consider using one of them.
5. Click OK, and apply Step 3 and 4 to the other Skype entry too.
6. If you have started Wampserver and is currently stuck at being orange, please exit Wampserver, and start it again. You should see that it now turns to green after a while, and now it is fully working. **Skype should also be working fine.** If it's not, try assigning another port.

Answer (score 0):

favorite

> Is there a way to which we can align them at boot up time that WAMP should
>   start first then skype. (Both use port 80)

Yes, you can simply not auto start Skype. Instead add a batch file to your startup folder with two commands in it. The first command would be to sleep while the WAMP stack powers up, the second command would be to start skype.

(e.g. `timeout /t 30` to pause for 30 seconds).

> Both use port 80

Both use port 80 by default. Both can be changed.

For a web based system your basic URL is `http://host.domain.tld:80`. If you do not type either http or :80 then these will be guessed clippy style.  Changing them might not be preferred (though it certainly would solve things).

For skype there is no need to specify a port. Skype can use almost any port it wishes to. It just likes to try ports 80 and 443 because those are often opened in firewalls. However it can and will work fine with any other port. And IIRC it will select there on its own.

The option to try to bind to ports 80 and 443 is merely to minimise problems for most people with a proper FW setup. It also causes enough problems for people who do more than average stuff with their computers and Skype has (or had, not sure what a version of Skype which runs on XP has) an option not to bind to these ports. This is why Skjerns answer will work.

---

Example file.

```
@echo off
echo Welcome to your new and improved Skype delayed start batch file!
echo Doing nothing for the next 10 seconds
timeout /t 10
echo Starting Skype
START C:\"Program Files (x86)"\microsoft\skype.exe
```

Explanations:

`@echo off` is not needed, but without it all the commands will be echo'd to the screen. Echo off makes it cleaner.

`echo Welcome to your new and improved Skype delayed start batch file!`  Just some filler text. Not needed, but especially when trying something new it is nice get get status information.

`timeout /t 10` This waits 10 seconds or until you press a key.

`START C:\"Program Files (x86)"\microsoft\skype.exe` this starts a program and closes the batch file (cmd) window. Without the `start` part a black box will remain open until you close skype.

Note: Adjust the path to wherever you actually installed skype. Since Skype if now bought by Microsoft I am guessing in Microsofts standard path, which is %program files%\firmname\program_name.

Comment: what file extension do i need to save in  startup folder?

Comment: .bat. E.g. a file named `delayed_skype_start.bat`. I'll add an example to the post so I can use markup.